# Confirm dialog posting on Cancel button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following `<a>` tag to display a simple confirm which it does. However, when I click the Cancel button it still performs the post method. From my understanding, having the `return` in front of confirm should cause the form to not post if the Cancel button is clicked.

```
<a href="#" 
   data-potr-action="delete"
   data-potr-val="@item.RID"
   onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Request?');"
   class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete
</a>
```

I have this code at the end of the page but I don't think it has anything to do with the issue. I didn't thinking it would fire the click event when selecting Cancel in the Confirm dialog.

This just takes the values in the data-action and data-value and stores them to a hidden field. This is done on click which it shouldn't be getting to.

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Hook events on buttons and anchors
      buildClickEvents();
    });

    // Hook events on buttons and anchors
    function buildClickEvents() {
      $("[data-potr-action]").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#EventCommand").val(
            $(this).data("potr-action"));

        $("#EventArgument").val(
            $(this).attr("data-potr-val"));

        $("form").submit();
      });
    }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question no confirm doesn't block form post. It return true if pressed "OK" or false if pressed "Cancel" button. See this from [W3c](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

What you could is as below:

```
function buildClickEvents() {
  $("[data-potr-action]").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Request?');
    if(result == false){
       return;
    }
    $("#EventCommand").val(
        $(this).data("potr-action"));

    $("#EventArgument").val(
        $(this).attr("data-potr-val"));

    $("form").submit();
  });
}
```

And remove the below from a tag:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Request?');"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("[data-potr-action]").on("click", function (e) {
    if(confirm("your message")){
        $("#EventCommand").val(
            $(this).data("potr-action"));

        $("#EventArgument").val(
            $(this).attr("data-potr-val"));

        $("form").submit();
    }

    e.preventDefault();


  });
```

Comment: Was about to post the same. Also be sure to remove the onclick attribute from the HTML tag

Comment: That works if I only have a delete button in my form but in this case I have both a Filter button and a Delete button. That's why there is a data-action value. On submit that value gets set in a hidden value and then passed to the Post method. In the post method I use a switch statement to look at the value is. If it's "filter" it does one thing, if it's "delete" it does another. I doing this based off of a Paul Sheriff blog.